# O que são meta dados e como funcionam em bases de dados?

Tags: sql

Tenho pesquisado sobre meta dados, e falaram que é mais rápido pra trazer informações quando se trata de milhares de linhas de dados.

Tenho um banco de dados imenso e queria mais segurança e mais fluidez na hora de trazer os dados dele.

Comment: Poderia dar mais contexto sobre o que está falando, e qual sua dúvida?

Comment: sua pergunta está meio vaga, difícil de responder, por exemplo *"falaram que é mais rápido pra trazer informações quando se trata de milhares de linhas de dados"*. **Metadados** de uma forma simples são dados que explicam outros dados, eles não necessariamente são a informação de um campo do banco de dados, não vejo com isso tenha relação com performance.